# Como passar os dados de uma pesquisa feita em ajax/php/mysql para um textarea com ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Estou trabalhando em um painel de controle para site onde são feitas as postagens das notícias.

Por ele você consegue editar as notícias caso necessário, estou usando o `CKEDITOR` em meu `textarea`, a consulta é feita por meio de `ajax`/`php`, mas não consigo jogar o texto pesquisado no `banco` para edição de volta no `textarea` com `CKEDITOR`. Alguém pode me dar uma força?

```
function editaTextoNoticia(idd) {
    var url = "buscaEditarTextoNoticia.php?id=" + idd;
    req2.open("Get", url, true);
    req2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req2.readyState == 1) {
            document.getElementById('textoEditar').innerHTML = 'Carregando...';
        }
        if (req2.readyState == 4 && req2.status == 200) {
            var resposta = req2.responseText;
            CKEDITOR.instances.textoEditar.updateElement();
        }
    };
    req2.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Poste a parte do código com erro

Comment: Clique em editar a pergunta amigo, antes disso leia o tour para aprender usar o site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta está vaga, sem código, etc. Mas já trabalhei com o `CKEditor` e não tem segredo, verifique as seguintes questões:

1 - Referencie o arquivo `js` do editor:

```
<script src="libs/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

2 - Adicione `class="ckeditor"` na `textarea` que deseja usar o editor:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor"></textarea>
```

3 - Se usar `PHP`, dê um `echo` para escrever o texto no editor:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor"><?php echo $meuTexto; ?></textarea>
```

4 - Se usar `Jquery`, use:

```
$(".ckeditor").val("meu texto");
```

Comment: Bem vou tentar explicar melhor.
Eu tenho uma página de edição de notícias.
Estas notícias estão cadastradas em um banco mysql.
Necessito fazer a edição de uma notícia, onde os dados são buscados através de uma pesquisa ajax/php no banco, ao retornar o resultado, o texto deve aparecer em um textarea que usa ckeditor. Não consegui uma forma ainda de mandar o texto retornado da pesquisa para o textarea.
No caso, o trecho de código que te enviei é o fragmento em ajax que pega os dados a serem pesquisados e retornam as informações obtidas para o usuário.
Espero que tenha ficado mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

Na linha

```
  var resposta = req2.responseText;
```

Você adicionou o que retorna do ajax na variável resposta, mas não jogou para dentro do seu campo, você tem que inclui-lo com (no caso de textarea)

```
 CKEDITOR.instances.idDoTextarea.setData (resposta)
```

Onde idDoTextArea é o Id do seu textarea (logico rs)

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer isto, se o textarea estiver puro funciona, mas usando o CKEditor ele fica em branco.

Comment: Assim funcionou! Obrigado!

Comment: de nada, bom desenvolvimento ai.